# Minimize Access Application then Maximize it and set focus back to Access Application

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to do what i describe in Title but when the minimizing with DoCmd.Minimize seems to work as the access window disappears. But then when i try to maximize it back with DoCmd.Maximize, it doesn't give focus back to access window.

PS : i use theses methods in a function called by a acDialog form.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/72WHnxB here is some screenshots :

Comment: what i want is to get back to access after closing the java window

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting focus on your control/form?

```
DoCmd.Maximize
Form_MyForm!MyControl.SetFocus
```